# Persistent store load callback in ExtJS 4.1.1

Tags: json, load, store, extjs4.1

I need a way to catch the JSON response every time my datastore has loaded. My first try was to use the `autoLoad` property but the callback fires only on first load :

```
autoLoad: {
    callback: function (records, operation) {
        // do something with operation.response.responseText
    }
}
```

So, I have decided to extend the `load` method :

```
load: function (options) {
    var callback = options && options.callback;
    return this.callParent([Ext.apply(options || {}, {
        callback: function (records, operation) {
            // do something with operation.response.responseText
            if (callback) {
                return callback.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        }
    })]);
}
```

It works, but I wonder if the framework already provides a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a load listener to the store and grab the current request from it's proxy when the load event is fired.

```
var myStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.store", {
   ...whatever here
   listeners: {
       load: function(store){
           store.getProxy().activeRequest.options.operation.response.responseText;
       }
   }
});
```

Thats if you want the response text specifically.  If you want the response as a JSON object, you can use `store.getProxy().reader.rawData;` which is a little simpler